# Decorators being executed twice in angular 2 env

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-decorator

While playing around with decorators, on an ng2 (ang-cli-based) env., I wrote a .spec.ts file.
I was expecting this:-

- The expression evaluation will be top down
- The results would be functions and will be executed bottom up.

Both are happening (as expected), which is fine, but, everything is being executed twice.

See below:=

```
testchild1.spec.ts

//fdescribe("Ang2: just execute this suite only", function(){

//(function) expression evaluation is top-down
//results (of functions) are then called as functions from down-top

function f(){
  console.log('f() expression evaluated ');
  return function(tar, x:string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){
    console.log('f() called');
  }
}

function g(){
  console.log('g() expression evaluated ');
  return function(tar, x:string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor){
    console.log('g() called');
  }
}

class C{
  @f()
  @g()
  somemethod(){
    console.log('inside somemethod');
  }
} //class C ends.

//});
```

O/p:-

```
D:\js\Ang2\proj2\ngrxproj03>ng test src/app/testchild1/testchild1.spec.ts
Your global Angular CLI version (1.1.2) is greater than your local
version (1.1.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active19 06 2017 15:30:16.929:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
19 06 2017 15:30:16.932:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
19 06 2017 15:30:16.940:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
19 06 2017 15:30:30.788:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket qmmNpsc8yjStv6b-AAAA with id 45423503
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'f() expression evaluated '

Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'f() expression evaluated '
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'g() expression evaluated '

Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'g() expression evaluated '
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'g() called'

Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'g() called'
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'f() called'

Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0) LOG: 'f() called'
Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 6 (skipped 4) SUCCESS (0.092 secs / 0.187 secs)
```

See how everything is being called twice. 
Am i doing something (that is obvious) wrong?
Any pointers would be great. (Have wasted half a day on this)